# Netbeans 8.2 : GlassFish 5 Server, deploy, null false - The module has not been deployed

Tags: netbeans-8, glassfish-5

I'm a new Java WebEnt student, and I'm having issues deploying some basic Entity Classes and JSF Pages.

I loaded up some things without any edit to the files, and when trying to deploy. I get the "\nbproject\build-imp.xml:1045 The module has not been deployed" message. I checked the GlassFish server and here is the beginning log:

```
   java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; 
   columnNumber: 18; Deployment descriptor file META-INF/persistence.xml in 
   archive [classes].  cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found 
   starting with element 'properties'. No child element is expected at this point.
```

The rest of the log is pasted below
https://pastebin.com/7rXsyRit

EDIT
Pastebin to include the XML files in WEB-INF and persistence.xml
https://pastebin.com/6kRJyA54

Thanks for the help/advice

Comment: Update your post to show the content of **META-INF/persistence.xml** for the application you are trying to deploy (**WebApplication1**).

Comment: @skomisa Added it last night, thanks for all the help

Comment: [1] OK. One strange thing is that the error is being reported for line10 column 18 of **persistence.xml**, yet that file is only 9 lines long. Does the posted error definitely refer to the instance of **persistence.xml** that was posted? [2] Regardless of that, you can remove the line containing `<properties/>`. I doubt if it's causing a problem, but removing it can't hurt. After doing that can you try deploying again to see if the error message changes?

Comment: I doubt it'll be referring to any other persistence.xml. I am getting now another error after removing that  <properties/. https://pastebin.com/VbKkg4mt log is posted here

Comment: Update: I went and followed the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426853/connection-could-not-be-allocated-because-user-id-length-0-is-outside-the-ran and I was able to finally run my program thanks for all the help!

Comment: Cool. But to be clear, was the line containing `<properties/>` in **persistence.xml** the cause of the original problem? If so, could you post an answer to your own question? That would help others  in the community who might face that problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the issue was `<properties/>` after I had removed that and tried to deploy, I had gotten that error which following the instructions in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426853/connection-could-not-be-allocated-because-user-id-length-0-is-outside-the-ran)  had resolved.